# Setting selected property in react mui menu item not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to set the selected prop with [react mui menu item](https://v3.material-ui.com/api/menu-item/). I have a multiple select menu list, where I have a field `allValues`, that on clicking it, toggles the selection of all menu items. And that part works just fine. The code looks like this:

```
        <Select
          multiple
          value={selectedValues.map(klasse => klasse.id)}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event.target.value, onChange, idToValues)}
          input={<Input id="select-multiple-chip"/>}
          classes={{root: classes.select}}
          renderValue={selectedIds => (
            <div className={classes.chips}>
             {selectedIds.map(classId => (
               <Chip
                 key={classId}
                 label={idToValues[classId] && idToValues[classId].classCode}
                 className={classes.chip}
                 onDelete={(event) => onChange(selectedValues.filter(class => class.id !== classId))}/>
             ))}
           </div>
         )}
         MenuProps={MenuProps}
       >
      {!!allValues.length &&
        <MenuItem value="allValues" selected={allValues.length === selectedValues.length}>
          All classes
        </MenuItem>
      }
      {allValues.map(class => (
        <MenuItem key={class.id} value={class.id}>
          {class.classCode}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
      </Select>
```

I can see in the dev tools that `allValues` and `selectedValues` are of the equal `length`, but the `selected` prop is still `false`. How is that possible, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score -2):

Try adding () brackets like:

```
selected={(allValues.length === selectedValues.length)}
```

Comment: it is still the same